# paypal error in android paypal integration

Tags: android, paypal

when i try to pay via paypal it generates an error from paypal..

> 

```
11-05 20:57:08.600: W/paypal.sdk(2831): X SN:38 PayPal Debug-ID: 43d2bc84ba495 [live, 2.6.1;release]
11-05 20:57:08.600: E/paypal.sdk(2831): request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
11-05 20:57:08.600: E/paypal.sdk(2831): request failed with server response: "name":"AUTH_RC_RISK_FAILURE","debug_id":"43d2bc84ba495","message":"checkout-session
```

is NON_PAYABLE","information_link":"https://api.paypal.com/docs/api/#AUTH_RC_RISK_FAILURE"

Comment: in sandbox it works properly...in live it generates an error...

Comment: What don't you understand about this?

Comment: "AUTH_RC_RISK_FAILURE" is generated for what reasons ?

Answer (score 1):

That error simply indicates that the payment was rejected by PayPal's risk and fraud detections systems.  I recommend you communicate directly with PayPal's MTS support line or customer support to determine why it rejected that payment.